# Connections to Webmin via HAProxy are forwarded to port 10000 (HAProxy listening on 443)

Tags: haproxy, redirection, webmin

**EDIT**

Own solution at the of the question.

I am using a HAProxy (on a rented virtual machine) to be able to connect to some applications I am running at home.
This works perfectly fine for almost all of my backends.
What doesn't work very well is the following setup:
HAProxy running on port 443 in mode http having a backend with server port 10000 (Webmin) because connection works but after logging in I am being forwarded to port 10000 and after changing the port back to 443 I can use Webmin. This is not the expected behaviour.

**HAProxy defaults**

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    log /dev/log local0 info
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    #option forwardfor
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    balance                 leastconn

    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats uri /haproxy/stats
    stats refresh 10s
    stats show-node
```

**HAProxy frontend definition**
This is a catchall frontend because I only have one IP on the rented virtual machine and I am using different backends depending on the host header.

```
frontend catchall_http
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt MY_CERT
    acl letsencrypt path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    acl app_ns1 req.hdr(host) -i ns1.example.com
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;\ includeSubDomains;\ preload; if { ssl_fc }
    use_backend ns1.home.example.com if app_ns1
    default_backend backend-not-found
```

**HAProxy backend definition**

> http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
> is commented in because I tested with and without.

```
backend ns1.home.example.com
    acl valid_http_method method GET HEAD POST
    http-request deny unless valid_http_method
    #http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    server ns1.home.example.com ns1.home.example.com:10000 ssl check check-ssl verify required ca-file CA_CERT
```

---

```
# just to get the initial necessary cookies for login
curl --request GET --cookie-jar webmin_curl_cookies --cookie webmin_curl_cookies https://ns1.example.com/
curl --request POST --data @webmin_request_payload --cookie-jar webmin_curl_cookies --cookie webmin_curl_cookies https://ns1.example.com/session_login.cgi
```

The result is:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying HAProxyIP:443...
* Connected to ns1.example.com (HAProxyIP) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=ns1.example.com
*  start date: Aug 14 10:55:38 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 12 10:55:38 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "ns1.example.com" matched cert's "ns1.example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /session_login.cgi HTTP/1.1
> Host: ns1.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: redirect=1; testing=1; sid=SESS_ID
> Content-Length: 31
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 31 out of 31 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 09:40:48 GMT
< Server: MiniServ/1.953
* Replaced cookie sid="SESS_ID" for domain ns1.example.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: sid=SESS_ID; path=/; secure; httpOnly
< Location: https://ns1.example.com:10000/
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload;
< 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
```

I think the main cause for the unwanted behaviour is the **Location** header in the response.
How can I resolve this behaviour?

---

Own answer to my question:

In the backend add

```
http-response replace-value Location ^https://ns1.example.com:10000/$ https://ns1.example.com/
```

and it works. I don't know if this is a best practice solution and I'd definitely like to know that but it works for me.

Comment: Answers go below in the answer box. People will think your question is unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

I had to add the following line to the backend

```
http-response replace-value Location ^https://ns1.example.com:10000/$ https://ns1.example.com/
```